# The effect of changing $g$ for an elastic bouncing ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

Suppose there's a bouncing ball who's collisions with the ground are elastic (so the ball's energy is conserved). If we were to then slowly adjust the gravitational acceleration $ g $ on the planet somehow, how does that affect the ball's final velocity and maximum height?

It seems that the final velocity of the ball the moment before impact should be the same both before and after $ g $ had been adjusted. Because the moment before impact all of the energy is contained in $ \frac{1}{2} mv^2 $ which is independent of $ g $. Whereas the final height of the ball should be different, as at the maximum height all of the energy is contained within $ mgh $, which is $ g $ dependent.

However the problem I'm trying to answer asks for the change in velocity which leads me to believe I'm incorrect. While it could technically be a trick question, I'm guessing that there's most likely something incorrect with my thought process. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear to me that energy will be conserved if the field is reduced. It seems this is assuming that the potential energy is stored in the object, but is it?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure I understand the significance of the changing field -- does "very long time" not mean it is unimportant given (the presumably much shorter) timescale of the bouncing superball? And if the change in $g$ is significant, I'm not seeing how this problem is solvable without knowing $g(t)$.

Comment: Is this a homework or test question?

Comment: @DavidWhite So this is a question from an old exam given to us to study off of.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the question asking for the speed at the ground when $g = 0.9g_0$ ?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation. Since the current state of your question seems to be asking the site to check your work, I'm voting to keep the question closed.

Comment: If you have any specific reasons to believe your thought process is wrong, try to focus more on them ("Due to reasons A, B, C, I think X, but doesn't this contradict D?"). Just asking "Did I do it right?" is hardly useful for other users, and hence not suitable for the site.

Answer (score 1):

Energy is conserved.  For coefficients of restitution less than 1 (the normal case), some of the ball's "bouncing energy" is turned into heat upon each bounce, and the ball slowly comes to rest on the ground.  IF the coefficient of restitution is 1 (no loss of energy on bouncing), what does that tell you about the kinetic energy and velocity of the ball as the value of g decreases?  In addition, what does that imply regarding the maximum height that the ball reaches upon each bounce as g decreases?

Comment: So, energy is conserved... Say a ball bounces, and at the bottom, it has max KE, min PE, then at the top it has zero KE, and max PE. When at the top, the field giving $g$ is turned off and $g=0$. Where's the energy and what happens?

Comment: The gravitational field did negative work on the ball all the way to the top of its path, and slowed the ball down as a result.  If you turn off the gravitational field at the point where velocity is zero, the gravitational field can't do positive work to pull the ball back down.